# Can't update Desktop icons extension

Tags: updates, gnome-shell-extension

When I update Desktop icons extension, It shows "Can't install "Desktop Icons":
this is an extension enabled by my current mode, I can't install manually any update in this session." How do I solve this? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

And install extension from site https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/